# Picking two numbers - Calculate the probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We take randomly two numbers without replcement from a box that contains the numbers $1,2,\ldots , 10$.

Calculate the probability of the following events :

a) A = their sum is $11$

b) B = their product is even

c) C = the smaller one is $4$ or $5$

$$$$

I have done the following :

a) To get the sum $11$ we can have the $5$ combinations :  $1+10$ , $2+9$ , $3+8$ , $4+7$ , $5+6$

In total there are $10\cdot 9=90$ possible combinations.

So we have the probability $P(A)=\frac{5}{90}=\frac{1}{18}$.

b) The product is even if at least one of the two numbers is even.

So for the first number there are $10$ possible number to take.

In total there are $10\cdot 9=90$ possible combinations.

So we have the probability $P(B)=\frac{5}{90}=\frac{1}{18}$.

c) The smaller number is $4$ or $5$. So do we have to calculate the probability of the union of $E_1$ : the smaller one is $4$ and $E_2$ : the smaller one is $5$ ?

Comment: In (a) I suspect either your $5$ should be $10$ or your $90$ should be $45$.  Your answer to (b) is clearly too small and you seem to have copied and pasted your answer to (a), since the answer must be substantially more than $\frac12$.  Your approach to (c) would work if you manage to calculate the probabilities of the two events

Comment: At (c) the probability that the smaller number is smaller than $4$ is $\frac{3}{10}$ and the probability that the smaller number is smaller than $5$ is $\frac{4}{10}$ so the result for (c) is $\frac{3}{10}+\frac{4}{10}=\frac{7}{10}$, right?  @Henry

Comment: No - $\frac7{10}$ is far too high ($1,2,3$ are more likely to be the smaller value, so it must be substantially less than $\frac12$.  I would expect the answer to have $45$ as the denominator

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a)$, please note that we could choose any of the $10$ numbers as the first number. Then there is exactly $1$ second number out of remaining $9$ that gives sum of $11$.

So the probability is $\frac{1}{9}$.

In the way you wrote, you should have also counted $10 + 1, 9 + 1$ etc. and the answer should have been $\frac{10}{90}$

For $b)$, only if you pick both numbers odd, you do not get an even number as product. So the probability is,

$1 - \frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{4}{9}$

$c)$ yes, you have to simply add probabilities for both cases - when the smaller number is $4$ and when the smaller number is $5$.

Comment: At (c) the probability that the smaller number is smaller than $4$ is $\frac{3}{10}$ and the probability that the smaller number is smaller than $5$ is $\frac{4}{10}$ so the result for (c) is $\frac{3}{10}+\frac{4}{10}=\frac{7}{10}$, right?

Comment: At (a) we have to consider both cases $1+10$ and $10+1$ for example, right?

Comment: For $(a)$, you are correct. For $(c)$, it is asking that $4$ or $5$ is the smaller one which means the other one has to be bigger. For  $4$, it is $(4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10)$ but it can also be $(6, 4)$ instead of $(4, 6)$ so that is $12$ cases out of $10 \cdot 9$, that is $\frac{12}{90}$. Similarly for $5$, it should be $\frac{10}{90}$ and then add them to get $\frac{22}{90}$

Comment: @MaryStar is this clear? any more questions on this?

Comment: Yes, everything is clear now! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: you are welcome :)